# LongListMultiSelector blocks gesture events for selected items

Tags: c#, xaml, events, windows-phone-8

In the following XAML when any `TextBlock` is selected in `LongListMultiSelector`, that `TextBlock` stops recieving `Tap` event (and any other gesture events) but instead becomes unselected when I tap it again. How can I change this behavior such that `TextBlock` will be always responding to `Tap` regardless of it's selection state?

```
<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- When TextBlock is selected, Debug_WriteLine_Tapped does not get called -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Tap="Debug_WriteLine_Tapped" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
```

Basically what I'm looking for is a behavior similar to that of standard Mail app where after selecting a bunch of letters they still recieve `Tap` events because I can still expand/collapse any of them (except that in my case it's a simple `TextBlock`s and not `ExpanderView`s).

Answer (score 0):

Works OK on my machine. When I tap these 3 items I get the expected messages in the debug log.

```xml
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Tap="TextBlock_Tap_1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

```cs
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataContext = "Foo Bar Baz".Split(' ');
}

private void TextBlock_Tap_1(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("TextBlock_Tap_1");
}
```

Depending on your Scenario WP8 exposes the [UseOptimizedManipulationRouting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.frameworkelement.useoptimizedmanipulationrouting%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property which might prove useful. Setting UseOptimizedManipulationRouting=false causes LongListSelector, Pivot and other controls to not swallow events for nested controls. A good place to set that would be on the root control of your LongListSelector.ItemTemplate.

Comment: Just tried setting `UseOptimizedManipulationRouting` to false on `LongListMultiSelector` and it didn't help. Selected text block still gets unselected instead of responding to Tap.

Comment: I have no problems with `LongListSelector` because items can't be selected there. In `LongListMultiSelector`, when item is not selected it responds to tap as it should and I see output in console. But once it becomes selected it's tap response it to become unselected, not to fire it's event listener, that is the behavior I'd like to get rid of.

Comment: Perhaps I use the words wrong, under "selected item" I mean an item that has a checked checkbox in front of it in `LongListMultiSelector`.

Answer (score 0):

The toolkit uses this sig to respond to the tap.

```
private void OnItemContentTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
```

The sample defines the datatemplate separate from the LongListMultiSelector construct in the

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

section and references it as

```
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmailItemTemplate}.
```

See LongListMultiSelectorSample.xaml in the toolkit for the example. The sample is actually incomplete and can be confusing at first. Just ignore the BuddiesPivotItem and the GridModeItem, unless you want to finish it and make the whole thing work.